# Error CS1061 when disabling script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to disable the script PlayerMove, but there seems to be a problem on line 20.

> DisableMove.cs(20,22): error CS1061: 'int' does not contain a
> definition for 'enabled' and no accessible extension method 'enabled'
> accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How should I modify it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DisableMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    int StopMove;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var StopMove = GetComponent<PlayerMove>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            StopMove.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have declared `StopMove` to be of type `int` inside the `DisableMove` script - Line 7, which doesn't have any `enabled` property/field. This is what gets accessed inside `Update` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have created StopMove as integer type, also you are hiding that in the Start().
Update line 7 and 12 of the script as follows:

```
PlayerMove StopMove;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    StopMove = GetComponent<PlayerMove>();
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what type of StopMove is now?

Comment: glad that I could help!!

Comment: the type of StopMove is PlayerMove now, that I believe must be a MonoBehavior

Answer (score 0):

You have declared two "StopMove" variables, one in the class (`int`) and one in the `Start()` (`var`) method.

When you call "StopMove" in `Update()`, the script finds the variable (`int`). It cannot find the variable (`var`) because it is created in the `Start()` method and cannot be accessed inside another method.

I would set up the script like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DisableMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerMove StopMove;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StopMove = GetComponent<PlayerMove>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            StopMove.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```